# How do I authorize in express and node using the res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, spotify-app

I am playing around with Spotify's API and I am trying to get the authorization from the user
using res.redirect, but the authorization dialogue is not showing up. Here is the code. Additional info the redirect URL is localhost:3000, and the js script is connect to a static folder which has one html file .

```js
const Joi = require('joi');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const request = require('request');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); //middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  .use(cors())
  .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/user', (req, res) => {

  const client_id = 'b*****************';
  const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  const scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + querystring.stringify({
    response_type: 'code',
    client_id: client_id,
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri

  }));


});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you’re implementing authorization in a mobile app, single page web app, or any other type of application where the client secret can’t be safely stored.
`Authorization Code with PKCE Flow` in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-pkce-flow)

I will demo a more simple version `Authorization Code Flow` but the concept is the same.

Authorization Code Flow in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow)

[image]

Demo code save as `demo.js`

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())

// for raw JSON of Body
app.use(express.json());

const REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost:3000/callback' // mine is http://localhost:3000/callback
const CLIENT_ID='<your client ID>'
const CLIENT_SECRET='<your client secret>'
const SCOPE=['playlist-read-private']
const PORT = 3000
const PLATLIST_ID='<your playlist ID>'

// User login URL
app.get("/user", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPE}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url)
})

// callback URL
// mine is http://localhost:3000/callback
app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const code = request.query["code"]
    await axios.post(
        url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        data = new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
            'code': code
        }),
        config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            params: {
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            },
            auth: {
                username: CLIENT_ID,
                password: CLIENT_SECRET
            }
        })
        .then(resp1 => {
            axios.get(
                url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${PLATLIST_ID}`,
                config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${resp1.data.access_token}`
                    }
                }
            ).then(resp2 => {
                return response.send(JSON.stringify(resp2.data));
            })
        });

})
// use your <your redirect URL>'s port
app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Listening on : http://localhost:${PORT}`) })
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install axios express cors
```

##### Run the server

```
node demo.js
```

##### Login to get a token by Browser

```
http://localhost:3000/user
```

##### Login Dialog will show

[image]

##### Result from express server

[image]

##### Scopes

Each API need to match scope,
Example,

| API | Scope | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Get Playlist | playlist-read-private | https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-playlists-tracks |
| Create Playlist | playlist-modify-public, playlist-modify-private | https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/create-playlist |

```
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/scopes
```

Comment: I am only getting the login dialogue only once after that it's not showing again, what should I do?

Comment: Change the redirect URI from "http://localhost:3000" to "http://localhost:3000/callback" at Dash board in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559444/issue-im-trying-to-pause-spotify-playing-using-a-python-script/76560961#76560961) and change code from `app.get("/", async (request, response)`  to ``app.get("/callback", async (request, response)`` in demo.js, Then try again.